# How do shields work in the game I-War?

Tags: independence-war

In [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100383/why-werent-the-shields-up-already#comment232585_100385), @GrimmTheOpiner claims

> ...shields are a universal Sci-Fi trope and Star Trek is no more guilty than any/many others! The only "shields" I can bring to mind that were explained differently were in the computer game "iWar" [sic].

Can someone explain what is unique about the shield mechanics in *I-War*?

(I'm assuming this is a reference to [*I-War* (1997 video game)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-War_(1997_video_game)) and not [*I-War* (1995 video game)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-War_(1995_video_game)).

Comment: according to these guides - looks like there is nothing specifically different about these shields than Star Wars / Star Trek shielding https://www.giantbomb.com/independence-war-the-starship-simulator/3030-8415/ |  https://www.i-war2.com/documents/help/tactics/combat-guide - hardly definitive, thus just a comment  -

Comment: both links work for me: https://www.giantbomb.com/independence-war-the-starship-simulator/3030-8415/

Comment: https://www.i-war2.com/documents/help/tactics/combat-guide

Answer (score 3):

The [manual for Independence War](http://files.replacementdocs.com/Independence_War_-_AKA_I-War_-_Manual_-_PC.pdf) describes the function and operation of shields in this fictional universe.

> **SHIELDS**
>   The NSO 929 is also fitted as standard with two Displacement array shields fitted on wide swivel mountings. Although provided as a defensive mechanism, they may be used offensively, albeit at close range.
>
> The principle of linear displacement has been used as a method of propulsion for over 200 years. Its potential as a defensive device is a more recent innovation. **The shield array projects a steerable region of disrupted space. Radiation or material passing through that space is displaced in random directions by amounts of up to 100meters.**
>
> The shields region of disruption can be between 100m to 200m from the array itself. The region can vary in radius between 2 and 10 meters. The newest shield arrays can easily block the blast from a particle beam cannon.
>
> An important point to remember is that the shielding zone must be kept between the ship and any hostile adversary. For this reason, the LDA is mounted on a fast linkage mechanism which can automatically track hostile vessels and keep the ship protected. **The NSO-929 is fitted with two such LDAs mounted at complementary positions - each capable of covering one hemisphere.**
>
> The LDA has also been used with some success as a hostile weapon at low range, by being able to displace elements of the enemy ship's hull.

The [manual for Independence War 2: Edge of Chaos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_War_2:_Edge_of_Chaos) gives some additional info about their tactical uses and weaknesses.

> **LDA shields**
>
> Combat ships are usually protected by one or more Linear
>   Displacement Array (LDA) shield systems. LDAs are an offshoot of LDS
>   technology that uses local spatial distortions to disrupt a small area of
>   space in front of the shield projector. This disperses the energy of an
>   incoming weapon, preventing it from damaging the hull. Or that’s what
>   the technical manual says. All you need to know is that if you see a
>   purple flash when you shoot a ship, you didn’t do it any damage.
>
> *“Shield coverage varies from ship to ship. However, the drives
>   are always vulnerable, so cover your ass while shooting
>   theirs.”*
>
> Another important point to remember about shields is that each LDA
>   decides which is the most likely enemy to fire at you and tracks that
>   vessel with the shield projector. You can use this to your advantage by
>   getting your wingmen to attack your target. The target’s LDA will not be
>   able to deflect the weapons from both attackers if they attack from a
>   different angle.

Comment: ...so pretty much the same as Star Trek imo

Comment: @NKCampbell - Very much not so. In Star Trek the shields are a projected force-field. In I-War, the shields are a projected region of disrupted space-time.

Comment: @Valorum - Because that's so much more scientific. :)

Comment: @NKCampbell : The *TNG Technical Manual* describes shields in very similar terms: *"the deflector system creates a localized zone of highly focused spatial distortion"* (Section 11.8, pg. 138).